# after open event of pop up not working

Tags: javascript, html, events, jquery-mobile, popupwindow

I have a **jquery mobile popup**. I want after it opened to perform some things. The problem is **not** coming to the event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    $("#alertsPopup1").bind({
        popupafteropen: function (event, ui) { alert('popup'); }
    });
});
```

Here the pop up in the html:

```
 <div data-role="popup" data-corners="false" class="alertsPopup"
                id="alertsPopup1" data-theme="e" data-overlay-theme="b" class="ui-content">
                <p>
                    aaaa</p>
            </div>
```

I can not understand what the problem is, it passes the bind without problems (I tested in Chrome's console).

I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: Is the popup appearing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First don't use  document ready with jQuery Mobile, sometimes it will trigger before jQuery Mobile can process page correctly inside the **`DOM`**. Read **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)** why.

Instead of document ready you should use proper jQuery Mobile page events. Read more about them in a previous link.

Also if possible use delegated event binding. Basically use on function to bind an event and bind it to a document level. Delegated event binding should solve the problem of document ready usage, mainly because it doesn't care if popup exist / don't exist inside the **`DOM`**.

#### Javascript :

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $(document).on("popupafteropen", "#alertsPopup1",function( event, ui ) {
        alert('popup');
    });  
});
```

#### HTML :

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">       
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#alertsPopup1" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a>
        <div data-role="popup" data-corners="false" class="alertsPopup"
        id="alertsPopup1" data-theme="e" data-overlay-theme="b" class="ui-content">
            <p>
                aaaa</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Jgajv/